# Ansible Checking UIDS

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a script I would like to use that essentially checks the UIDs in /etc/passwd and greps for specific UIDs, reporting it's findings to a file that is then sent back to my PC. Works as expected but I am trying to fine tune it. Here is what I have so far:

```
    - name: Checking to Make Sure the UIDS are safe for foo Users
      shell: cat /etc/passwd | awk -F ':' '{print $3}' | grep 150[0-1]
      register: foo

   - local_action: copy content={{ ansible_hostname.split('\n') }};{{ foo.stdout }} dest=/Users/blah/playbooks/roles/check_user_uids/files/foo_stdout.log
```

Here is what I see in the log file:

```
[u'server-one'];1500
1501
```

What I would really like is to do something like:

```
[u'server-one'] 1500
[u'server-one'] 1501
```

Can someone show me an example of how I can do this using JinJa templating or advise if this is possible to do with local_action module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/common_return_values.html#stdout-lines

If you debug the variable `foo`, you'll see that there is a return value `foo.stdout_lines` containing a list of your output.  You can iterate over that in your current task.

```
- local_action: copy content={{ ansible_hostname.split('\n') }};{{ item }} dest=/Users/blah/playbooks/roles/check_user_uids/files/foo_stdout.log
  with_items: "{{ foo.stdout_lines }}"
```

Or you could use that return value with the template module to achieve the same thing.  Check out Ansible's and Jinja's docs for more info.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_templating.html
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/

Comment: This is pretty close to where i would like it to be and makes it readable enough for me. Thanks :-)